# Internal Memory type of Samsung Mobiles

Tags: android, memory, ntfs, fat32

I have samsung galaxy S2.i have lost my all data in my cell phone. I am going to recover my data through some software , My question is that what is the type or format of Memory used in Mobile phones like in computers or laptops it has FAT32 or NTFS then what is the internal memory type of samsung mobiles.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android internal data type format is FAT32 .